# Crashlytics-Firebase crash report doesn't make sense

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

I have a crash reported like:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$c0.a' on a null object reference
at com.xx.xx.Fragment$23$1.run(TestFragment.java:4)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

How to find the `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$c0.a`? Where is the crash happening?

Absolutely nothing to do with NullPointerExceptions. This question is about finding variables names in Crashlytics reports when classes are not symbolicated in the crashlog.

Comment: Absolutely nothing to do with it, can't you read? It is about finding variables names in Crashlytics reports when classes are not symbolicated in the crashlog.

Comment: Well, the crash report says it's happening on line 4 of `TestFragment.java`. Start by looking at that file, and including relevant parts in the question?

Comment: @DanGetz  the report was not symbolicated, in line 4 there is nothing otherwise I would not ask. The question has already been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the next row in the report:

```
at com.xx.xx.Fragment$23$1.run(TestFragment.java:4)
```

where `$23$1` is the first inner class in the 23th inner class in your fragment. From the stacktrace it looks like a `Runnable` posted to a `Handler`.

It's your `RecyclerView` that is null there but in case you want to decode what specific field the obfuscated name `c0.a` corresponds to, have a look at mapping.txt belonging to that build (can be found in build/outputs/mapping directory).

Comment: Thanks so much, this not for humans)

I got his:

androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder -> androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$c0:
    boolean mInChangeScrap -> o
    int mIsRecyclableCount -> m
    int mFlags -> j
    long mItemId -> e
    androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView mOwnerRecyclerView -> r
    java.util.List FULLUPDATE_PAYLOADS -> s
    androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler mScrapContainer -> n
    android.view.View itemView -> a

Comment: Should not this found by Crashlytics? Maybe I should submit the map somehow? Thanks so much again! I think I found the place, amazing help!

Comment: Usually the fabric/crashlytics gradle plugin takes care of the mapping file yes.

Comment: "It's your `RecyclerView` that is null there" – Hmm, that's not how I'm reading that: `Attempt to read from field '...View ...RecyclerView$c0.a' on a null object reference`. That would mean `RecyclerView$c0` is null, not the `RecyclerView`, yeah? A null `ViewHolder`. Anyhoo, just nitpicking. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM the code is question: 

 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          
            public void run() {
                 mRvFilters.scrollToPosition(0);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                   
                    public void run() {                        
                            mRecycleView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(pos).itemView
                           .performClick();
                    }
                }, 300);

            }
        }, 400);

Comment: Basically a terrible hack for scrolling a recyclerview to the start and click on the first item. I added a catch to findViewHolderForAdapterPosition and the crash disappeared. Not so sure it will always work :(

Comment: I'm very grateful for the help, as it was a very urgent issue. I can't understand why some reports are not symbolicated. I'm in Catalina..maybe that? I will try to contact Firebase support and ask why! Thanks again!